# awk command combining if and for

Tags: awk, for

I have a csv file 20 columns. in the first part of the file is the geolocation info. What I am trying to do is to find the geolocation data for a certain record. 
First if identifies the user "ROSA". On that line search through the first 10 columns and if any of them contains "GeoLocation" print only the next record not the whole line.

```
awk  -F"," '($0~/ROSA/) {for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {($i~/GeoLocation/) print $(i+1)}}' filename.csv
```

I came up with the line above but I am getting flagged for syntax error right at the "p" in print.

Can you guys spot what I am missing?

Comment: You say you want to combine `if` and `for`, but your code contains no `if`, which is your issue.  This could be a simple typo.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that on the main level you have blocks of `pattern { code }` (the pattern is usually just an expression) and there's no need to explicitly say `if`. Or to even put parenthesis around the pattern. But inside the code block you need to spell the if-statement out, so: `{ if ($1 == 123) { print $2; } }` or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`awk  -F"," '($0~/ROSA/) {for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {if ($i~/GeoLocation/) print $(i+1)}}' filename.csv`.
Additionally I would avoid searching whole line for ROSA of You know field number or at least include the delimiters in regex to not match substrings.
Also You do not want to print the next record (that would be the whole next line) but the next field...

Comment: `($0~/ROSA/)` is the same as just `/ROSA/`.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes but mostly You know the username is in a specific column and You use `$x == "ROSA"` instead... Or at least match on a whole field if You really don't know (`/^(.*,)?ROSA(,.*)?$/`).

Comment: Thanks both of you for your answer. It seems the missing part was the "if". I was assuming it will work without it just like at the first one. Actually I am not searching the whole line just the second column. Whole line was one of the trial runs not the final version.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from

```
awk  -F"," '($0~/ROSA/) {for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {($i~/GeoLocation/) print $(i+1)}}' filename.csv
```

To

```
awk  -F"," '($0~/ROSA/) {for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {if($i~/GeoLocation/) {print $(i+1)}}}' filename.csv
```